# the priority of primary key and multi-column index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE student (                                  
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                   
  name varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,                 
  age int(11) NOT NULL,
  update_time timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),                                   
       KEY idx_name_age (name,age),                         
       KEY idx_name_age_update_time (name,age,update_time) 
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And I use `EXPLAIN` to get some information of how indexes work in MySQL, and I found one thing that's got me confused when I execute the sql like this:

```
EXPLAIN 
  SELECT * FROM springboot.student
    WHERE id>1 AND id <5 AND NAME = 'tank' AND age =23 ;
```

And the result:

```
id   select_type   table     type     possible_keys    key            key_len   ref             rows  Extra        
------  -----------  -------  ------  ---------------------------------------------  ------------  -------  -----------  ------  -------------
1  SIMPLE       student  ref     PRIMARY,idx_name_age,idx_name_age_update_time  idx_name_age  391      const,const       1  Using where
```

I wonder why it's got this to me.

Comment: What're you confused about?

Comment: confused about why it makes the way unexpected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no inherent priority. You influence the SQL optimizer, but cannot control it. And that is actually good. Rule-based optimizers are obsolete for quite a while now, and Cost-based optimizers are all the rage.

What happens is the [cost-based] SQL optimizer produces an execution plan that depends on many parameters. For example:

- Size of the table.
- Indexes present.
- Distributions of values of each column.
- Selectivity of the filtering conditions.
- How current the table statistics are.
- etc.

It seems you want the table to be read by index using the primary key. Translated to optimizer terms, you want:

- **Access**: by the primary key index, using an **Index Range Scan**.
- **Filtering**: by the `NAME = 'tank' AND age = 23`.

However the optimizer decided on someting different:

- **Access**: by the index `(name, age)`, using an **Index Seek**.
- **Filtering**: by the primary key index.

In general Index Seeks are much faster than Index Range Scans. Maybe that's why the optimizer chose the second one.

Did you actually measure the execution time? Remember the plan is not the query. Measure, measure, measure.

Comment: I fail to understand your question. Usually equality `=` is more valuable (read **Index Seek**) rather than inequality `>` (read **Index Range Scan**) when it comes to index search.

Comment: I mean sometimes it's not working as we expect in MySQL index,right? The optmizer would estimate which execution plan could be even faster beyond indexes, right?

Comment: There are a bunch of reasons why the SQL optimizer chooses one plan or another. I listed just a few reasons above. Most of the time the optimizer is right and what you expect is wrong, due to lack of details the optimizer may have at hand.

Comment: So `Read Index Seek` has higher priority than `Read Range Scan` with the comparison between `Primary key` and `Multi-column` index based on the example as above, right?

Comment: No, there's no such thing as a priority. Depending on many conditions it may be selected before or after other "operators".

Comment: @tank the optimizer has estimated the number of matching rows using `idx_name_age` as 1.  The primary key, presumably, matches 3 rows, but they would have to be filtered, since `name` isn't part of the PK.  Remembering too that the PK is implicitly included at the right-hand side of the secondary index, It's kind of obvious why the chosen plan is the winner -- you have an index containing everything in the predicate, im a useful order.